# Why would one number one's paragraphs?

Tags: word-usage

I understand this is done in formal letters (composed by government officials or lawyers).

```
1       I would love to congratulate...

2       You may wish ...

...

6       I look forward to meeting you ....
```

Comment: Without more context it is impossible to know why authors make the choices they do.

Comment: In general, paragraphs are numbered so that they can be unambiguously referenced later.

Comment: Think about it, Counsel: "Your Honour, I want to draw your attention to a piece of evidence given yesterday." Judge: "Where is that?" Counsel: "If Your Honour turns to page 223 of the transcript, at line 13 the witness said.." XYZ. Same reason parliamentary transcripts are made, marked with pages and line numbers.  So when a politician said "I never said that", then you can cite the exact words they said by reference to page number and line, and everyone can follow along.  Sometimes the lines or pages may be timestamped.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the English language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paragraphs are numbered so that they can be referred to easily when needed to. In Religious books such as Qura'n, **sentences** are numbered so that when a sentence is quoted by someone, it can be validated easily.